# Interact with the database through HTTP or socket connection?

Tags: c#, http, sockets, persistent

At the minute I have several hundred queries every few seconds sent from one C# program (lets called it Program1) to a HTTP server, which then processes the XML content using business logic and updates the database as appropriate.

Would it be more efficient if instead of putting my business logic in the web server (PHP back end), I should instead put the business logic in another C# application (lets call it Program2) that can maintain a persistent connection both with the database itself and also Program1 or any other programs that might want send Program2 data.  Or should I just stick with my existing HTTP route?

Answer (score 0):

I would save the XML on the webservers harddisk and then import those files one after the other with a windows service that has a persistent connnection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use a similar design for our corporate business rules engine. (PHP Webservice Backend with Multi-platform clients)

We have had good success with this model. Using the HTTP protocol provides you good  flexibility should you want to change the back end business logic code or platform. PHP running as an Apache or IIS module with persistent db connections can get the efficiency up.